# Can I force an iPhone user to upgrade an application?

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

Is it possible to force the user to upgrade once there is a new version of my application available in the iTunes Store?

I am presently working on an application. However, I want to force the upgrade whenever I upload a newer version, because the upgrade will have more features and I want to discard the previous version. Is this possible by default with iPhone or do I have to write my own implementation to check the current version and compare it to the store?

Comment: As an iPhone user, I have seen many bad updates. I prefer to be given the choice whether to update or not. Even Apple and Microsoft don't force security updates. You can always opt out or restore an older version. If its a security or feature requirement, you can tell your users the update is necessary, or the app will not function. You can block their credentials until they update, but it will still be their choice.
You give me a bad update, I will delete it and restore the old one from itunes.
Even now, users have placed an iPhone request to be able to block app updates.

Comment: I've had this problem for a while myself. I released this little tool called [**Harpy**](https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Harpy) that checks the installed version against the App Store version. If a newer version is available in the store, it notifies your end-user and prompts them to download the app when your application launches. [**Grab it on Github**](https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Harpy).

Comment: I have an app that is in the same situation; It has version checking logic, as we desire the ability to do a forced upgrade if needed/wanted. An early beta has been rejected by ITunes for having this logic. What I don't understand is that if Harpy is used for an IOS app and only the Update option is offered to the user, would that be allowed, and why?  As I look at the Harpy github info, I don't see a way to avoid updating if 'Update' is the only option presented (similar to what we've had rejected).  Is the important difference that iTunes is kept as the primary info source vs an outside one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only way system handles updates of your application is prompting user that update is available in standard AppStore application.
Also, standalone application is not aware of available updates so you'll need to implement your web service where application can check if the current version is valid.
And I'm not sure if this conforms with Apple rules on applications, like (can't find proof-link though) you cannot upload trial versions for an application.

*** EDIT ***
This answer is no longer true. See other upvoted answers for current truth.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  i shall have to try it coz clear cut upgrade is mandatory for my app. Present version deals with free subscriptions and upgrade has to include payments. Thats the reason i am trying to keep it forced.

Comment: @HariKaramSingh, yes, you can use approach mentioned in other questions. Unfortunately I cannot delete this answer while it is marked as accepted

Comment: @Vladimir You might not be able to delete, but you can always update. It will serve as an updated reference whoever bump into it later.

Answer (score 38):

I have done this feature by getting version from itunes webservice and comparing with the current version.. Following is my code

```
        NSString *version = @"";
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=<Your app ID>"];
        versionRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [versionRequest setRequestMethod:@"GET"];
        [versionRequest setDelegate:self];
        [versionRequest setTimeOutSeconds:150];
        [versionRequest addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"]; 
        [versionRequest startSynchronous];

        //Response string of our REST call
        NSString* jsonResponseString = [versionRequest responseString];

        NSDictionary *loginAuthenticationResponse = [jsonResponseString objectFromJSONString];

        NSArray *configData = [loginAuthenticationResponse valueForKey:@"results"];

        for (id config in configData) 
        {
            version = [config valueForKey:@"version"];
        }
   //Check your version with the version in app store
        if (![version isEqualToString:[itsUserDefaults objectForKey:@"version"]]) 
        {
            ProAlertView *createUserResponseAlert = [[ProAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"New Version!!" message: @"A new version of app is available to download" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles: @"Download", nil];
        [createUserResponseAlert show]; 
        [createUserResponseAlert release];
        }
```

And put the app id in the itunes link see the code below..

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    // the user clicked one of the OK/Cancel buttons
    if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        NSString *iTunesLink = @"itms-apps://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftwareUpdate?id=<appid>&mt=8";
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesLink]];
    }
}
```

Note : You need JSONKit frame work and ASIHttp frame work to make the webservice calls..

Comment: This is really good. Still are you using above concept? or any restrictions for it? @Dilip Rajkuma

Comment: Hi @ganesh I am not developing iOS apps.  But I guess it will still work, let me know if it doesn't..

Comment: IMHO, The webservice mechanism seems overkill for this case. See @datinc's `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]`. But use `lookup?id=<Your app ID>` as seen above, not datinc's `lookup?bundleid=..".

Comment: But when the app is "In Review" state then how apple will review because it just shows alert every time. Am I right?

Comment: @DilipRajkumar,  
But when the app is "In Review" state then how apple will review because it just shows alert every time. Am I right?

Answer (score 21):

You can detect if the app needs an update then take some custom action like alert the user an update is available. Here is a code snippet that detects that an update is available.

```
-(BOOL) needsUpdate{
    NSDictionary* infoDictionary = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
    NSString* appID = infoDictionary[@"CFBundleIdentifier"];
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=%@", appID]];
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSDictionary* lookup = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

    if ([lookup[@"resultCount"] integerValue] == 1){
        NSString* appStoreVersion = lookup[@"results"][0][@"version"];
        NSString* currentVersion = infoDictionary[@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
        if (![appStoreVersion isEqualToString:currentVersion]){
            NSLog(@"Need to update [%@ != %@]", appStoreVersion, currentVersion);
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: BundleIdentifier may change for every next releases. Better to go with "App ID" as it does not change.

Comment: to clarify @GaneshGuturi's comment:  replace `lookup?bundleId=` with `lookup?id=`.  And use your app's "Apple ID", rather than looking up the bundle identifier. So the two lines before `url =` are not needed; just hardcode the "Apple ID" from your app's itunes connect page.

Comment: This is a good answer, using something like `[appStoreVersion compare:currentVersion options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedDescending` to compare the two versions may also be desirable, for example if you want to avoid potential App Store review issues, since the version in review will always be different from the App Store version. Of course, this only works if you increase version in every release (not going from version 2.0.0 to 1.0.0).

Answer (score 19):

This question was originally posted 7 years ago, and while some of the answers remain relevant, here is a more up-to-date approach.

I recommend https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Siren which is Swift 3 compatible and can be installed with Cocoapods or Carthage.

CocoaPods, Swift 3 support:

`pod 'Siren'`

Carthage:

`github "ArtSabintsev/Siren"`

Comment: It's working with **Swift 5**.

Answer (score 17):

If you absolutely have to, you can launch the App Store so that your users can get the latest version from there.  I would recommend making this optional, or at least presenting a dialogue first.

```
// iTunesLink should be your applications link
NSString *iTunesLink = @"http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=284417350&mt=8";


[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesLink]];
```

Comment: But how determine if what is in the store is a newer version?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve - you could scrape the latest version from iTunes page, or easier still keep a small html file with the latest version and check it from your client. Among other ways.

Answer (score 9):

There's no automated way to do it, you would have to write something manually.

Comment: https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Siren look at that please.

Answer (score 8):

A system for forced upgrades *should* be part of every application that has a dependance on something external to that application.  Both Apple and Google claim that if an app uses something external then that external API should live forever, never change, etc., etc., but that's simply unrealistic.  And if that's the case, if the services that the app depends on can change then there **MUST** be a way for the app to check and see if it should restrict functionality and prompt the user to get the latest version or things will simply mysteriously fail.

This could and should be something that Apple and Google provide, but they don't so every app outside of a few games needs to build this, SO...

I've started a rails based open-source (Apache 2.0) project to create a solution to this problem.  It's called Application-[Ctrl], and it's very much a work in progress, but you are welcome to use it and I welcome contributions of any kind.  If I can get this up and running in my spare time I'll provide this to all app developers with some very reasonable level of free service and of course every company will always be able to spin up it's own deployment.

It's here on GitHub: https://github.com/SlalomDigital/ApplicationCtrl

*Contribute and help me solve this problem for good!*

Answer (score 6):

My app update to the App store was just rejected exactly for this reason.  We added a feature to check the installed version against the current release and if it's not a supported version, we force them to update.

Apple rejected this.

So back to the design board!

Comment: I'm curious, did they specify which App Store guideline this violated?

Comment: I have an app that is in the same situation; It has version checking logic, as we desire the ability to do a forced upgrade if needed/wanted.  An early beta has been rejected for having this logic.  Any idea why your app's version checking logic would not be allowed, but it seems from various posts that [harpy](https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Harpy) is allowed?

Comment: How exactly did they discover that you show this screen if they always test with the latest version?

Comment: We are also having force update feature in our iOS app which checks the minimum supported version of web services and force updates if needed. It was never rejected.

Answer (score 4):

Your business/design plan should never contain the phrase "force the user". People get angry when you make them do something. Imagine a user in a hurry who opens your nifty little app one morning only to discover you are forcing him to upgrade before he can use the app for what he needs. Imagine he's stuck out in the wilds having to use Edge to download. He won't be happy.

If you follow this plan long enough, one of your upgrades will inevitably introduce a noticeable bug. If you force users to use a buggy version they will rebel.

I have been conditioned by experience to cringe whenever I see "more features" used to describe a new version of software because this inevitably means feature bloat. Designers tend to keep grafting more and more features onto apps until one app does everything. This is particularly dangerous on a platform like the iPhone where making one app do to many things rapidly overwhelms the interface and the responsiveness of the app.

Edit01: My comment here [How to Update an Application After Users Pay For Upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219734/how-to-update-an-application-after-users-pay-for-upgrade/2221999#2221999) might also be relevant to your plans. If your upgrade design cuts Apple out of the revenue loop, its a non-starter.

**Update:**

Just to clarify based on a comment below: Yes, sometimes you do have to require users to upgrade. However, that is much different from ***designing*** the app ***from the start*** to force users to upgrade every time the developer releases a new version.

Such a design is intended to make the developer's life easy and not the user's. Every time a user has to spend time upgrading for a benefit they did not ask for and perhaps do not want, you've taken time and resources from the customer. Design that offload time and effort from the developer to the user are bad designs because people ultimately buy software for their own benefit. When you decrease that benefit, you decrease the softwares ultimate profitability.

So, no designer should design software that forces the users to do something the user does not wish to unless it is an absolute technical necessity. This  is of course a rule of thumb but it is a very good one.

Comment: I agree that "Force the User" is really bad behavior.  However there are some cases where a forced update path may be relevant.  For instance, I came looking for this answer because I have a multi-user persistent server based game (Kind of like a MMORPG), and I need to force an update any time I am adding features to the server that may not be compatible with older versions.  However this is an odd use case.  Most of the time a better solution can be engineered.

Comment: I disagree, it's not ALWAYS a bad idea to force a user to update. What if you're making a game and the users find an exploit that allows them to boost their online scores or achievements?  if the developer fixes the exploit and releases the update, the cheaters won't "want" to upgrade since they know the update will prevent them from cheating.  if you can't force the update, then how to you prevent the cheaters from using the exploit?  you can't!  and that's a disaster scenario for all the players who love your game and choose not to cheat and they'll simply stop playing. Your thoughts?

Comment: I didn't say always, I said its a bad business-plan/design. The OP wants to design the app to force upgrades as part of the design for the benefit of the developer so he doesn't have to support older versions. That's a bad design. Sometimes you do have force an upgrade for security or other valid reasons but designing you app to force upgrades "because I don't want to do the work of supporting old versions," is bad design. Users will accept necessary upgrades but being forced to upgrade without obvious customer need really ticks people off.

Comment: I disagree, of course, you need to force users to update some times.

Comment: I don't get why this post has been upvoted so much.  The OP wasn't asking "SHOULD I force an iPhone user to upgrade an application?" so this reply isn't addressing the question and is just an opinion piece.  There MANY valid reason why you would need to force the user to upgrade.  Just look at Xbox Live, which has been in production for years and has a very large user base.  It requires the user to update the dashboard every time there is a new update available.

Comment: And another thing, websites essentially "force users" to update all the time.  Since everything is server side, websites are updated without the user's consent at the developer's whim.  How often has Google, Facebook, even SO changed over the years?  ALL websites are updated ALL the time, forcing the user to use the "latest version" without ever opting in.

Comment: @OpenUserX03 - 1) Sometimes the answer to "how do I do that?" is "don't do that." But you're right it something of opinion. That was nearly 3 years ago when  StackOverflow were less focused and such answers were acceptable. 2) Yes, websites like Facebook do force updates but it is easily their most hated feature.

Comment: @OpenUserX03 - Had the OP used the term "require users to update to continue using the software," I would not objected so strongly but the repeated use of the word "force" indicated a dangerous mindset in which he seeks to control and exploit the user instead of helping them. It's an absolutely fatal mindset. We cannot compel user to buy or use our software so if a we ***plan*** our relationship with our customers with the presumption we can "force" them to do anything, we're doomed from outset. Long term, it's a fatal design decision more lethal than any conceivable software bug or failure.

Comment: I've down-voted this answer. I'm not stupid, I don't need a preachy answer. I know it's not a good idea to force users to do something if there's no good reason. I happen to have a *very* good reason to do it and I came here in the hopes of finding out the best way to accomplish it.

Comment: Yeah this sounds like it's from a preachy product focused developer which is real cute. In most enterprise apps, this will become a requirement at some point. Banking applications do it very frequently. I have to do it for discover and bank of america a few times a year. 

If you're in the App store I'd code it into your APIs (and if you don't have APIs, I'd suggest you make one for this reason). However, non-app store apps can use hockeyapp to manage updates. Not my favorite product but it works for us.

Comment: @Chris Harrison - 1) This answer is 5 years old. Times and tech have changed 2) If you have a "good reason" i.e. one that provides immediate and obvious benefit to the end user e.g. a security upgrade, then my argument does not apply. 3) Read everything carefully. The goal of the OPs "forced" upgrades was to ***provide benefit to the OP***, not the end-user, a fatal design flaw originating from flawed business model. My answer is not preachy, it's enlightened self-interest. Anything that impairs the users utility or experience of the software will eventually hurt your bottom-line period.

Comment: @Kmurhpy - Your examples of enterprise and banking forced upgrades, all intended to maintain security and contact with external systems, have no relevance to this discussion. The OP merely wanted to escape the burden of having to support old software, regardless of whether that benefited his end user or not. I told him forced upgrades for that reason or any other reason that did not provide value to the end user, was a bad design.

Comment: @Chris Harrison - In answer to your question, the only way to force an upgrade through the apple store is to link the app to an external source such as a server and then constantly break the server so it will only work with newer versions of the software. This will force the user to keep upgrading in order to use the software.

Comment: The app could have security issues, force update is a needed feature, should actually be supported by the OS itself, I would like my bank mobile app to forme to update if they find the app vulnerable.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers indicate that one has to implement the forced updating functionality oneself.
It's a shame really, I wish it wasn't so.
My very first update to an iOS Application is to be released tomorrow, and fortunately
it won't be problem, as we have only made changes to the app.
However when we will eventually change the structure of our webservices, it would be really useful to
be able to force updates, so that our server doesn't have to support each and every app version.

There is an alternative to forced updates however, which seems to be unmentioned in this thread.
You could have every webservice call that produces data attach a schema to the data,
which tells the app how that data should be deserialised in your app.
This enables you to change the structure of data produced by get-requests without breaking deserialisation in the app.
Of course this assumes that the interpreter that you write, will not itself change, but that is a somewhat reasonable assumption to make when it has matured.

Post requests could be "schema-fied" through interaction.
With this I mean that before every post-request you make, you ask for instructions on how to call the up to date webservice.
You process the instructions using an attached schema for that, and then you make the actual call to the webservice.
Essentially this means that every post request requires 2 requests, but that can be okay.

However, no matter if you implement forced updating or schema interpretation the functionality has to be present in the app from day 1 when it hits the App Store.
Otherwise you're in the same mess. All of this complexity would be unnecessary if Apple implemented forced updating for us developers.
Schema interpretation would still be a usability improvement if forced updating existed though.
But it bugs me a little that Apple doesn't have forced updating, because at least with it, one could introduce one's own anti-break updating measures after the app was released.

Answer (score 3):

Hello for anyone in the future I found this tutorial which should help anyone, it helped me.

http://codewithchris.com/tutorial-how-to-implement-in-app-update-functionality-in-your-iphoneipad-app/

Edit (your code will look something similar to what's below):

```
// Try to get version 
NSString *versionNumber = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];

NSURL *updateUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourdomain.com/yourupdatefile.xml"];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:updateUrl
                                            cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed
                                        timeoutInterval:20.0];
NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                     returningResponse:&response
                                                 error:&error];
// Check no error, then parse data
if (error == nil)
{
    // Parse response into a dictionary
    NSPropertyListFormat format;
    NSString *errorStr = nil;
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:data
                                                                mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable
                                                                          format:&format
                                                                errorDescription:&errorStr];        
    if (errorStr == nil)
    {
        @try {

            // Try to see if the current app version exists in the update xml
            NSString *itunesUrl = [dictionary objectForKey:versionNumber];

            if (itunesUrl)
            {
                // Show dialog to ask user to update!
            }
            else {
                // Version not in XML
            }
        } @catch (NSException *e) {
            // Error with retrieving the key
        }
    }
    else {
        // Error with parsing data into dictionary
    }
}
```

However, upon further research i've found this to be a great solution for if you aren't using a server.

```
-(BOOL) needsUpdate{
    NSDictionary* infoDictionary = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
    NSString* appID = infoDictionary[@"CFBundleIdentifier"];
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=%@", appID]];
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSDictionary* lookup = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

    if ([lookup[@"resultCount"] integerValue] == 1){
        NSString* appStoreVersion = lookup[@"results"][0][@"version"];
        NSString* currentVersion = infoDictionary[@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
        if (![appStoreVersion isEqualToString:currentVersion]){
            NSLog(@"Need to update [%@ != %@]", appStoreVersion, currentVersion);
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

In the:

```
if (![appStoreVersion isEqualToString:currentVersion]){
                NSLog(@"Need to update [%@ != %@]", appStoreVersion, currentVersion);
                return YES;
            }
```

Portion of the code you set what you want to do if it's not equal, this is where you send the user to the app store to download the latest version.

Comment: can you say me where i have to put that portion of code in our application ?is it necessary to put in didfinish launch option or some where else? please guide me on this

Comment: @BhupatBheda hey sorry for the late response. Clone this code from GIT and it'll help you understand better. 

https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Harpy

When you go to migrate the code into your project, you will need to take the harpybundle, harpy.h and harpy.m that's it, from there you will need to make changes to your appdelegate (copy and paste the same stuff they have in your app delegate). 

You will have an option in the "HarpyAlertType", you'll see it in the project click the one you want to present the user when you update the app. Then you can forget about it. This WILL pass sub.

Comment: @BhupatBheda You will have three options for the HarpyAlertType:

HarpyAlertTypeSkip
HarpyAlertTypeForce
HarpyAlertTypeOption

Pick the one you wish to show. I hope i wasn't too late and was able to help, once again sorry for the late response I was on Vacation.

Comment: Hey Thanks for Your response i will try to do that as you mentioned Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
func appUpdateAvailable() -> (Bool,String?) {
        
        guard let info = Bundle.main.infoDictionary,
              let identifier = info["CFBundleIdentifier"] as? String else {
            return (false,nil)
        }
        
//        let storeInfoURL: String = "http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=\(identifier)&country=IN"
        let storeInfoURL:String = "https://itunes.apple.com/in/lookup?bundleId=\(identifier)"
        var upgradeAvailable = false
        var versionAvailable = ""
        // Get the main bundle of the app so that we can determine the app's version number
        let bundle = Bundle.main
        if let infoDictionary = bundle.infoDictionary {
            // The URL for this app on the iTunes store uses the Apple ID for the  This never changes, so it is a constant
            let urlOnAppStore = NSURL(string: storeInfoURL)
            if let dataInJSON = NSData(contentsOf: urlOnAppStore! as URL) {
                // Try to deserialize the JSON that we got
                if let dict: NSDictionary = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dataInJSON as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [String: AnyObject] as NSDictionary? {
                    if let results:NSArray = dict["results"] as? NSArray {
                        if let version = (results[0] as! [String:Any])["version"] as? String {
                            // Get the version number of the current version installed on device
                            if let currentVersion = infoDictionary["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String {
                                // Check if they are the same. If not, an upgrade is available.
                                print("\(version)")
                                if version != currentVersion {
                                    upgradeAvailable = true
                                    versionAvailable = version
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return (upgradeAvailable,versionAvailable)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below url to get the information of any app
You just know your Apple ID of your app.

You can get this Apple ID in the `itunesconnect.com`>your app>app information page

GET: http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=

Answer (score 0):

You can check application build number with

> Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String

Then Compare with your force update version and if you want open Appstore.

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://apps.apple.com/tr/app/--id--") {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apple does not provide any automated way to do it, you would have to write manually.

option 1. Can use the iTunes API to check the latest version for that particular App id. and show the pop-up to update the app.
option 2: you can use your own server to check the latest version. but you have to update your server whenever any update went to the apple app store.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to manage supported versions of your app is having a kill switch. You can either implement it yourself as suggested above or you could use a service that provides it as an off the shelf solution such as [Semaphr](https://semaphr.com).

Answer (score -17):

Of course there is no way. The user should make the decision if he wants to download a newer version of your application or not.

The AppStore will display if there arenew versions, so I also do not think that Apple will allow this. Also I do not know how you would do this? You could check it via an internet connection, but that's not the way Apple likes and so you won't have a chance to do this.

Comment: I disagree, it's not ALWAYS a bad idea to force a user to update. What if you're making a game and the users find an exploit that allows them to boost their online scores or achievements?  if the developer fixes the exploit and releases the update, the cheaters won't "want" to upgrade since they know the update will prevent them from cheating.  if you can't force the update, then how to you prevent the cheaters from using the exploit?  you can't!  and that's a disaster scenario for all the players who love your game and choose not to cheat and they'll simply stop playing. Your thoughts?

Comment: The way to think is okay, but if you can force an update, the user loose control, and that's not good. It's the users device, he can decide what he want to do with it.

Comment: :)) "It's the users device, he can decide what he want to do with it" - as if apple lets you do what you want with your device.

Comment: Sometimes you have to, like me recently in a medical app, you sure you would like to have an app with a wrong dosing on your kids medicine?! :)

Comment: What do you mean there is no way? You can always track the user by requiring GPS data access, and go there and point a firearm against his head FORCING him to update the app. 

Seriously, of course you can't force a user do anything, but as an app owner, you surely can offer options: update or keep the useless version of the app - just because it's my app, and I have to make decisions. And you know what - I'm really doing it because I add more value to my users, and don't want to waste time on backwards compatibility in a world where update takes a few seconds.

Comment: The answer is not accurate