# send update app to AppStore and notify users

Tags: iphone, app-store, notify

I have a question. I send App to AppStore. When I need send a update for the App, How notify the users that the App have new update? I put the key version with new version number. I need set other key for notify the users that exist new update App??

Thank you very much!

Comment: I dont know much but you can use push notification. Check the documentation

Comment: nebillo is right I have given an example code in this stack http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221436/can-i-force-an-iphone-user-to-upgrade-an-application/8988245#8988245

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users are notified automatically when they sync with iTunes or use the App Store app on their device.

---

#### Edited to add

You certainly can notify users yourself if you plan ahead. Create a method that makes a request to a location you control (even a free Google Page would work fine) to determine the current version and call it in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. Compare the number you retrieve to the version currently on the device and if the user is running an out of date version, notify them and provide a link to the App Store app where they can perform the update.

Whenever you come out with a new version just update the web page.

Answer (score 10):

Why don't use the iTunes Store API?
Having your application store id, you can fetch its info like this: http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=441252681

the "version" field it's what your're looking for.
oh, of course you get it updated for free!

Answer (score 3):

It's true that the App Store will notify users automatically, but they often miss the notification badge on the App Store App and don't update for a long time.

I wrote a class to inform users from within the app itself by polling the iTunes services to detect when the new version is released:

http://charcoaldesign.co.uk/source/cocoa#iversion

Basically it's an implementation of Matthew Frederick's idea above, but it's a complex enough task that you might want to use my class instead of rolling your own solution. Also, because it hits the iTunes services directly, you don't need to host and maintain your own version file.

Comment: Great tools you got there, with iNotify and iVersion. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything.
Your users will be informed automatically in the app store app or via itunes.

Comment: Grammatically speaking, you **DO** need to do nothing. ;)

Comment: do need to do nothing?  lol.  How about "don't need to do anything"... there we go...:)

Comment: Thanks :), for fixing the fix