# iOS, Core Data, update datamodel - How does it work?

Tags: ios, core-data, in-app-purchase

**Preambule**

Suppose, I have an iOS application, which is a book reader, and it uses Core Data for storing the books data. The first version of my app uses a rather simple data model, which i later will update. I want to sell my books via the "In App Purchase".

**Question**

If i update the application with a new datamodel, will the *iOS* application be responsible for converting the old books into a new version of the data model? Say, will the *iPhone or iPad* have to convert them? How will I motivate the users to update their apps to a new version when they buy books (in my app) in the new version, while still having an old version of the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update the data model, you use migration.

See: [Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/)

... for details. Note that you can in many cases rely on automatic migration.

> How will I motivate the users to
>   update their apps to a new version
>   when they buy books (in my app) in the
>   new version, while still having an old
>   version of the app?

You don't want to "motivate the users" to update because that is usually just a polite way of saying "force the user" to update. [Forcing your users to upgrade for anything other than unavoidable technical necessity is always a bad idea.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221436/can-i-force-an-iphone-user-to-upgrade-an-application/2221775#2221775)