# Coredata upgrade in new app version, leads to "unrecognized selector sent to instance" crash occasionally for some users

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have to add a new filed to my new App version, for example, "nickname". After adding, I have test upgrade to a current new version from old version, that's no problem, no any crash. So I submit app to somewhere while jailbreak's devices can upgrade my app before appStore approved to check my app stability.  However，I see such kind of crash in my crash statistics for new version:`-[User nickname]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb7d04e0`

```
Thread : Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x371b688f __exceptionPreprocess + 162
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x34ebb259 objc_exception_throw + 32
2  CoreFoundation                 0x371b9a9b -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 174
3  CoreFoundation                 0x371b8915 ___forwarding___ + 300
4  CoreFoundation                 0x37113650 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 48
```

Any suggestions about coredata upgrade, are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

See this:

[iOS, Core Data, update datamodel - How does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275674/ios-core-data-update-datamodel-how-does-it-work)

Chances are parts of your code are still trying to access the `nickname` property of `User` and you have removed that property?

Check your code for any methods/code that try at access this.

Comment: nickname is new added.The crash is occasional for some users.

Comment: Have you migrated the data properly.

Answer (score 0):

The database wasn't upgraded but you use the new functionality. Make sure you have the MOMs in one MOMD (they are versioned) and the correct one is marked as current

Comment: The crash is occasional for some users. Is it possible an bug in jailbreak device user?

Comment: I don't know of such a bug. of course he could manually have screwed with the app or the db...

Comment: maybe you can put in a NSLog to log the database model version being used and give that to the user if you are sure migration is set up ok