# Will AppStore reject my application if i force user to update to newer version available on appstore

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

I know there are numerous way to force user to update application, 
My question is, will Appstore reject my application if my application will not let user use it until he/she update application.

Comment: I don't know. But I see some apps won't run if I don't update new version

Comment: You might want to check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221436/can-i-force-an-iphone-user-to-upgrade-an-application)

Comment: No rejection. I am also do the same in my live app. And there is no issue. So enjoy. :)

Comment: @MihirOza have you ever faced any rejection from apple because you are forcing the user to update ?

Comment: @AKASHWANGALWAR No. Till now I have not faced any rejection issue because of force update.

Answer (score 6):

**NO.** Your application wouldn't be rejected if it forces user to update. We have been doing this for last 4 years now(a financial sector app). Whenever we find a vulnerability in the app or it includes a major security update, we discontinue the older version and force users to download the new one.

However it would be a good user experience if you let the user know why you are forcing them to update.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe. [This person posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42531046/502457) about being rejected for this. However many apps have done this for years without rejection. So either Apple is getting more sensitive to this, or that app implemented the update requirement in a really user-unfriendly manner.