# iOS Apple Developer App Guidelines

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

I've read through [Apple's iOS app submission guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#functionality), although my question is more in regards to the rules (if applicable) after it's been approved.

Basically what I'd like to know is if a developer is allowed disable certain functionality in an older version of an app so that the user is essentially forced to upgrade to a newer version? This could also include making the user download another completely separate app (that the functionality was previously in the old version) in the process.

Is this allowable, or is there something that specifically says that's against the guidelines/rules? If anyone knows the answer to this and could provide the source of the info that would be great. thx.

Comment: hopefully you mean to encourage people to upgrade to your new free version which has some dependency on a server feature and you don't want to support the old server version...

Comment: I suspect that disabling some app functionality when releasing a new version would be OK as long as the product description was revised so that there were no misleading claims.  Apple themselves have released downgraded versions of products at times.  (All that stuff about forcing people to do things, though, is pretty far-fetched.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This isn't a programming question, this as a question from a user of an application that has done just this.

Comment: @Wain: It could be that, but it seems like it could go either way there. There could be good reasons as you mentioned, or bad ones. Does Apple take that into account, and how would they actually know?

Comment: Please mark this question as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221436/can-i-force-an-iphone-user-to-upgrade-an-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't force user to upgrade app but if you want so or there is no other option then you can launch the App Store so that your users can get the latest version from there. or you can display some UI which does nothing except giving update option!!

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesLink]];  //your app's itunes link to open it when user open the app
```

You can refer [Apple forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/12779) and can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221436/can-i-force-an-iphone-user-to-upgrade-an-application).

hope this will help :)

Comment: The link to the other question was key, and apparently it's allowable. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome..... :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you really think anyone would download the new version? Customers would *swear* at you and find a different app. If they paid, they will ask for a refund, and Apple *will* give them the full refund. Since Apple only gives you 70% of the sales price, and the full refund comes out of your pocket, a full refund will cost you real money.

Apple's interest is in selling phones. You are welcome as long as you help them selling phones. If you are an ass and upset Apple's customers, Apple will do what they can to upset you.

Comment: Well the thing is, that is actually what happened. The app was free, but I never wanted to update it and they essentially forced it by disabling key functionality in the old version. It was done by a very large powerful corporation also, and I'd like to know if they broke the rules.

Comment: why don't you contact apple then?