# Does iTune provide any default way from which we can force iPhone users to upgrade app and stuck them to use with current version?

Tags: ios

I have created an iOS application and going to upload it on iTunes store. My question is whenever I will publish the new version on the store then I want to force users to upgrade the app and they should not be able to use the app so far. I know, we can do this using calling iTunes web service as suggested in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221436/can-i-force-an-iphone-user-to-upgrade-an-application) to check and stuck users to use the app with current version but I want to know there is any another way like iOS os can do it by own and no need to call API again and again to check version number.

Comment: why android tag?

Comment: No, Ios cant do that by own. You need to follow procedure given in link you have added here

Comment: No. Apple does not provide any such service. Force upgrade should by implemented by the developer himself.