# where to write the code that does force on an iPhone user to update iOS application in his iPhone?

Tags: ios

I need how Can I force on an iPhone user to update iOS application in his iPhone?
after searching I get the answer of this issue the fallowing link:
[Can I force an iPhone user to update iOS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221436/can-i-force-an-iphone-user-to-upgrade-an-application)

But  I do not have any idea where to write this code and I want to display the message that says the new version is ready at the first time the application runs  before launch page.

can any help me this issue.
please help me.

Comment: Check the current app version with latest app version with server and show a popup you need to update the app. don't allow user to dismiss the popup. so simple. after launch image only you can show there is no code display before that. 

Write your version check code on appplicationdidfinish launching

Comment: I think you can write code in response of all services and make decision!!

Comment: Check this https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Siren

Comment: Mr  Vinodh you said Write your version check code on appplicationdidfinish launching. please guide me where appplicationdidfinish is.

Comment: @user9713861it is in your appdelegate.m file if you are using Objective C and in appdelegate.swift if you are using Swift

Answer (score 0):

I added a viewController which behave as a splash screen. In this viewController I get current application version and sent to server for validation and show alert to user if his application is not updated. If user click on update then redirect user to appStore.

For reference image is attached.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [This](https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Harpy) library where you can use in both Objective C and Swift. And you can use it by using CocoaPods and manually.

And it supports

1. A three number versioning system (e.g., 1.0.0)
2. Also supports two-number versioning (e.g., 1.0)
3. And also supports four-number versioning (e.g., 1.0.0.0)

Check the link for more features.