# Can I give optional an iPhone user to upgrade/update an iOS application?

Tags: ios

**Is it possible optional that the user to upgrade/update once there is a new version of iOS application available in the iTunes Store?**

I am developing on an iOS application in objective c. So that, I want to give to the user an option if wants to upgrade/update  or not whenever I upload a newer version .
 I want to send a message via alertView whenever I upload a newer version .
 if he wants the click update to update new version for example and if he does not want click no to run the application.

**I get how Can I force an iPhone user to upgrade an application?**
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221436/can-i-force-an-iphone-user-to-upgrade-an-application)

please help us .

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle it manually by communicating with your back end.

From the back end, you can set if you want to force the user to update or skip it.

Comment: it works fine when user must update if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
      
        NSString *iTunesLink = @"itms://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-store/id1387381660?mt=8";
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesLink]];
    }.   how to redirect to the app main page if (buttonIndex == 0)
        {
            
           
        } it means whence does not want update]

Comment: Mr JackyW please help me

Comment: @MohamedAli if (buttonIndex == 0) { //dismiss your action sheet and dismiss any popup viewcontrollers you have }
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactionsheet/1622888-dismiss

good luck!

Comment: if I dismiss popup viewcontrollers  the screen will be black and do not redirect to the main page of my application

Comment: I see. Is it possible for you to check update at main page of the screen instead?
This way, after dismissing the popup, user will be able to continue use the app!